# Replacing tags in xml in bash

Tags: regex, xml, linux, bash, sed

I have an xml file that is of the following format:

```
<list>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <version>1.2</version>
</list>
```

The idea is that I always update the first version tag with a new version. And when I do so, I replace the subsequent tags.

For example, when I update the 1.6 version as the first  tag (which I know how to do), the following tags would be:

```
<list>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <version>1.3</version>  
</list>
```

I've tried to get two options going.

**First Option:**
My preferred option would be to search the xml file and replace the version tag i+1 with version tag i. Something like:

```
sed -E '2,/<version>.*<\/version>/s#<version>(.*)</c>#<version>\1</version>#' file.xml
```

Where I search for the second instance of version and replace it with the first instance of version (currently not working).

**Second Option:**
My second option would be to store the version tags in variables like:

```
version=$(grep -oPm1 "(?<=version>)[^<]+" file.xml)
version2=$(grep -oPm2 "(?<=version>)[^<]+" file.xml)
```

Then replace version 2 by version 1 and do the replacement:

```
sed -i "s/${version2}/${version}/g" file.xml
```

However, this options gives:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated 's' command.

And when I try:

```
sed -i "/$version2/s/${version2}/${version}/g" file.xml
```

I get:

> unterminated address regex

Obviously, the idea for either option would be to put the code in a loop so that I can run it i times. However, I am stuck and both options I've tried don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Don't use text-manipulation tools such as `awk` or `sed` to work with XML if you can at all avoid it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) While this specific subset may be so simple as to make the approach feasible, having the right tools at hand will avoid headaches later (if the file format gets extended; if someone adds comments to the front; etc).

```
new_version=1.6
xmlstarlet ed \
  -d '/list/version[last()]' \
  -i '/list/version[1]' -t elem -n version -v "$new_version" \
  <old.xml >new.xml
```

- `-d '/list/version[last()]'` deletes the last `version` entry in the list.
- `-i '/list/version[1]' -t elem -n version -v 1.6` introduces a new element named `version`, with the value `1.6`, in the position currently held by the very first version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could try using xmlstarlet, but how would you go about installing it on a centos machine? yum install xmlstarlet doesn't work. Once I get it installed, I'll give your code a try.

Comment: xmlstarlet is in the EPEL repository. See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL for installation instructions.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ! or # as separator in sed instead of /.

It breaks because your match and replace variables contain /

Comment: I tend to prefer `@`. `!` is meaningful to shells with history expansion, and many syntax highlighting engines see `#` as a comment character even in positions where it can't be used as such.